# What does this initialization of Class Variable mean in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, class-variables

I have three ruby scripts say, `A.rb`, `B.rb` and `Call.rb`.

I have a class variable `@@classvar` in `Call.rb` and I am initializing it like,
`@@classvar=[:A,:B]`.

What does the above statement actually do?

Comment: The two files A.rb, B.rb as well as the file name Call.rb seem irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
@@classvar=[:A,:B]
```

It means, set class method, or static method with name `classvar` as an array with two symbols, `:A` and `:B`.

Comment: so what does the @@classvar actually hold?

Comment: when i call say, @v=Hash.new, tmp=@v[:A], what will be in this case?